# PHP page redirect in condition statement

Tags: php, mysql, html, web-services

I'm currently working on a stock quote site, I have this condition in my pages when using quote symbols to search for information on quotes.  If the symbol isn't found in the database, I need to redirect the user to a "find a symbol" page.  Here is the condition statement.

```
if($result)
{ }
else
{
//page redirect
}
```

I need to know how to redirect someone to the page in my else statement, any advice?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect */
exit; // important to make sure nothing else gets executed after this line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
header( "Location: http://your-target-site.com/yourpage" );
exit;
```

It is important to know that the `header()` statement will fail if any other output has been generated. Make sure that your page produces no output before this statement.

Answer (score 1):

Output a location [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
{
    header('Location: http://yourdomain.com/nextpage.php');
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else said you use the header function in php, however this only works if there is no output before. If you do have output the only option is to use javascript.

`echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.example.com';</script>";`

This isn't a great solution as it doesn't work 100% of the time if the browser doesn't have javascript enabled. So only use this if you absolutely can't use header().

Answer (score 0):

[header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) is used to send a raw HTTP header. See the [» HTTP/1.1 specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616) for more information on HTTP headers.

```
if($result)
{ }
else
{
    header("Location: http://google.com");
}
```

See more examples here: http://ditio.net/2008/10/04/php-redirect-header-location/

Answer (score 0):

As long as there hasn't already been some output, just use the header() function.

```
header("Location: http://bleh.com");
```